# rmarkdown::pandoc_convert from md to pdf

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, pandoc

I am working in Rstudio on Windows. I know minimal Linux

R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

I have a markdown file (not an Rmarkdown) that i am trying to convert to a pdf. I am using the command

```
rmarkdown::pandoc_convert("test.md",to="pdf")
```

I receive the following error

```
Unknown writer: pdf
To create a pdf using pandoc, use -t latex|beamer|context|ms|html5
and specify an output file with .pdf extension (-o filename.pdf).
```

However the functions help has pretty much this exact example.

Advice on what the problem is? Do i need to install something? a pdf writer? What is that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in rmarkdown because no output was set. 
You have to use:

`rmarkdown::pandoc_convert("test.md", output = "test.pdf")`

or

`rmarkdown::pandoc_convert("test.md", to = "latex")`